# fetch custom post by meta key if key value is does not know

Tags: custom-post-types, meta-query

I am trying to fetch custom post by meta key,But I am unable to get this .
when I am trying to run query without meta value its showing blank.
any help

```
 $args = array(
                                 'post_type'         => 'mad_property',
                                 'post_status'       => 'publish',
                                 'paged'             => '-1',
                                                       'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'seasonaldiscountdesc',
            'value' =>'',
        'compare' => '='
        )
    )
                                                       );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `NOT EXISTS`. You will get all posts, which do not have meta field 'seasonaldiscountdesc'.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'mad_property',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'paged'             => '-1',
    'meta_query'  => array(
        'key' => 'seasonaldiscountdesc',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    )
);
```